# How to push span inside a div to right and make this text inside responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, position

I am trying to make bar skills. I made it create one. 
However there are some problem.

How to make this span float to right? i tried to use float didn't work. Any suggestion? And whenever I am trying to shrink the screen the text too small

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}

.flex {
 display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 10pt;
}

.bar { 
 width: 100%;
    background-color: #ccc;
    line-height: 18pt;
}

.fill {
  background-color: #7ef57e;
}

.tag {
 text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: #00A1A7;
    font-size: 2vw;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 1%;
}

span.value {
    float: right;
    font-size: 2vw;
    z-index: 1;
    
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="bar flex">
   <div class="bar fill" style="width: 75%">
     <div class="tag">Javascript</div>
    </div>
    <span class="value">75%</span>
  </div> 

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already set the `width` of `div` at the same level to `75%`, so now you can just use other `25%` for the `span` tag, this way it should fill all remaining space. And after that, you can simply align text of the `span` to the right side via `text-align: right`. Here is a live example:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box
}

.flex {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 10pt;
}

.bar { 
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ccc;
    line-height: 18pt;
}

.fill {
    background-color: #7ef57e;
}

.tag {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: #00A1A7;
    font-size: 2vw;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 1%;
}

span.value {
    text-align: right;
    width: 25%;
    font-size: 2vw;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="bar flex">
    <div class="bar fill" style="width: 75%">
      <div class="tag">Javascript</div>
    </div>
    <span class="value">75%</span>
  </div> 
</body>
```

Comment: ah thanks i thought the issue was the float thing. Thank you man

Comment: @sekti92, no problem. Notice, that I also removed floating from `span`, you don't really need it anymore